# Angular cannot render carousel with template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular with UI bootstrap components. My goal was to create carousel using templateUrl argument for slide render, but met some problems. First of all nothing appears when I run page, also I get tho errors:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=carousel&p1=slide
- Multiple directives [carousel, slide (module: ui.bootstrap.carousel)] asking for transclusion on:

Here is my code:
**home.html**

```
<section id="slider">
<!--slider-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="homeCarouselCtrl">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides"  template-url="pages/templates/offer-product-tplt.html"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controler**

```
mainApp.controller('homeCarouselCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.myInterval = 5000;
    $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
    $scope.slides = [
        {
            slideTitle: 'Free E-Commerce Template',
            slideText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
            slideImage: '../../images/home/cat1.jpg'
        },
        {
            slideTitle: '100% Responsive Design',
            slideText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
            slideImage: '../../images/home/cat2.jpg'
        },
        {
            slideTitle: 'Free Ecommerce Template',
            slideText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
            slideImage: '../../images/home/cat3.jpg'
        }

    ];
}]);
```

**template: offer-product-tplt.html**

```
   <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1><span>E</span>-SHOPPER</h1>
        <h2>{{slide.slideTitle}}</h2>
        <p>{{slide.slideText}}</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="../../images/home/girl1.jpg" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" />
        <img src="../../images/home/pricing.png" class="pricing" alt="" />
    </div>
   </slide>
```

Maybe someone can show me where I made mistake?

Comment: Have you tried using your template directly in your HTML instead of using template-url? Also, your `<slide>` element never closes.

Comment: it closes, just bad copy paste. I tried to make this egzample, everthing works. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#carousel

Answer (score 1):

The `templateUrl` attribute for carousel shouldn't be used in this manner. You should only override the default carousel template if you want to use your own HTML for slideshow controls. Here's the [default carousel template](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/carousel/carousel.html) FYI.

You'll need to move your `<slide>` into the `<carousel>`. If you want a reusable template for what's inside the slide, you could create a directive for that.